# Error removing old webhook

Tags: java, maven, robots.txt, telegram-bot

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación en java, con Maven, que  gestione el comportamiento de un Bot de Telegram, lo único que quiero hacer en principio es poder automatizar las respuestas. El problema es que a mi parecer la clase y el main están bien estructurados , pero me surge un problema que he podido observar que le ha pasado a mas gente, pero no encuentro una respuesta que me solucione el problema, el problema es el siguiente:

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: ***Error removing old webhook***
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot.clearWebhook(TelegramLongPollingBot.java:32)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi.registerBot(TelegramBotsApi.java:120)
    at pruebaTelegram.Ejecutador.main(Ejecutador.java:22)
```

Me sale este error, que dice que no puedo borrar los antiguos webkook, no se si el error puede ser ocasionado por un proxy que es lo que he podido leer a otros usuarios, o por que este mal picado el código, es el siguiente:

```
    package pruebaTelegram;


    import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
    import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
```

**(ESTA CLASE ES LA DEL BOT)**

```
public class GestionaPeticiones extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Override
    //Invocaremos a esta función, cuando el bot reciba un mensaje
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        System.out.println(update.getMessage().getText());

        //Obtenemos el mensaje que escribe el usuario
        String mensajeRecibido = update.getMessage().getText();

        //Obtenemos el id del chat del usuario
        long idChat = update.getMessage().getChatId();

        //Creamos el objeto mensaje
        SendMessage mensaje = new SendMessage().setChatId(idChat).setText("Hola caracola");

        try{
            //Enviamos el mensaje
            execute(mensaje);
        } catch(TelegramApiException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {

        return "miToken";
    }

}
```

**(ESTE ES EL MAIN)**

```
package pruebaTelegram;


import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;



public class Ejecutador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApiContextInitializer.init();

        //Creamos un nuevo bot 
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        GestionaPeticiones bot = new GestionaPeticiones();

        try{
            //Registramos el bot
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(bot);
        }catch(TelegramApiException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

En las dependencias , en el fichero pom.xml esta puesto lo siguiente:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
      <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```